# Send events to Azure Event Hubs -> Operation not permitted

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send) implementing Azure Event hubs on Java but I get the following exception.

```
com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Operation not permitted, errorContext[NAMESPACE: testhandheld.servicebus.windows.net. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:85)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler.notifyErrorContext(ConnectionHandler.java:351)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler.onTransportError(ConnectionHandler.java:253)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.run(ReactorExecutor.java:91)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.$r8$lambda$NrD3tar-eanl_T0ijanE5E0zkZY(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1731)
    at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubProducerClient.createBatch(EventHubProducerClient.java:199)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:40)
            ... 1 more
```

connection string has permissions to admin, read and write so I'm not sure about whats the problem.

EDIT:
I forgot to add permission to use internet on the android Manifest.

Comment: Looking at the callstack, onTransportError occurs when there is an issue creating/using the TCP connection. Can you try using websockets to see if that fixes your issue?

```java
var producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
    .transportType(AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS)
    .connectionString(connectionString)
    .buildProducerClient();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have followed the same [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send) to send Events to Event Hub using java and I'm able to achieve the expected results.
  [image]

[image]

> com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Operation not permitted, errorContext

- Regarding the above-mentioned error, try by reduce the batch size.
- Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-amqp-troubleshoot) to explore more about AMQP errors troubleshooting steps in Azure Event Hub.